# Exception in thread "main" java.io.EOFException while reading with objectInputStream

Tags: java

I'm getting eofexception I tried to solve it but didn't find an answer 
it is giving exception in ObjectInputStream line 
please help me out.

```
public class SearchIndex extends ObjectOutputStream {
  static Map<String, List<String>> map = new HashMap<String, List<String>>();

  public SearchIndex(OutputStream out) throws IOException {
    super(out);
 }

  public static void readIndex() throws FileNotFoundException, IOException, ClassNotFoundException {

     // create an ObjectInputStream for the file we created before
    File file = new File("res/searchIndex.txt");
    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(file);
    ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream(fis);

    System.out.println(ois.readObject());
    // read and print an int
    map =  (Map<String, List<String>>) ois.readObject();
    System.out.println(map);
    ois.close();
  }
```

help me solve this problem

Comment: Answer: When the input file is empty the FileInputStream will return -1 as output so, check if (fis != -1 ) then go further... because of FileInputStream returning me -1 the EOF exception is occurring .... hope this will help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is only because your file at location `res/searchIndex.txt` is empty.

Check if you have any data in your file..

Moreover, since you used `ObjectInputStream`, your text content won't get converted automatically into bytes.
If you are using `readObject()` for reading; then you have to use `writeObject()` for writing contents into file.

Comment: Thank you for reply,  Yes, my file is empty. I got over the effect by checking the readInt() is -1 or not. As you said , I used readObject() and writeObject() but the writeObject is writing some dump into the file. thanks in advance

Comment: I am developting simple search index; sample file entries look like this:  keyword: url1, url2, url3; keyword1: url2, url4; help me @Ashish

Comment: requesting you to open new question if you required any other assistance . also if your above exception is resolved ; can you accept it and close this question?

Answer (score 3):

Its an expected behavior, `ois.readObject()` reached end of the file and couldnt fine anything further. 
Handle it inside a try catch block

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I'm getting exception at creating ObjectInputStream object;

Answer (score -1):

You need to explicitly cast the object to String.

Use

```
 System.out.println((String) ois.readObject());
```

And it should work.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, the exception is not printing the object, but I'm getting exception at creating ObjectInputStream object;

Comment: @sreenathsirimala okay... where and how are you using the writeObject method in your code? can you please post it here?

Comment: I have removed entire logic and written on my own @megh vidani thanks for reply

Comment: If you have solved the issue, It would be great if you could share your own way of solving it so that it can help someone in the future. :)

Comment: I have added the answer in a comment :-) thanks for suggestion .@megh